# What is the difference between Patch data and Patch schema in magento2?

Tags: magento2, patches

I created an attribute in patch data class, and
I created a table cloumn in the patch schema class.
I don't know the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema patch** is a class in Magento 2 that contains schema modification instructions so you can add, update, or delete columns in any custom table or EAV table. A schema patch contains custom schema modification instructions. These modifications can be complex. It is defined in a `<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/Setup/Patch/Schema/<Patch_Name>.php` file and implements `\Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface.`

On the other hand, A **Data patch** is a class that contains data modification instructions. It is defined in a `<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/Setup/Patch/Data/<Patch_Name>.php` file and implements `\Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface.`